# Following Udemy course "Modern React with Redux". Very strange issues, if you can help me figure them out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jsx, babeljs

First, as I follow the lectures, I deleted "src" folder entirely, but in the browser on the "localhost:8080" page content "Hello There!!!" from index.js file remained intact on the page after refreshing. First oddity.
Researched questions&answers for similar experiences -none. Asked Question 6 days ago, answer- none.

As I continued with the lectures, constructed new "src" folder and brand new "index.js" file. Inside of that file I wrote, following the tutor, an error-driven code which should produce an error in the console.
That code is:

```js
const App = function() {
 return <div> Hi! </div>
}

React.render(App);
```

The expected and never showed error should be:
Uncaught Reference Error react is not defined.

None. Just blank in the console. And the old "deleted" "Hey There!!!" content on the page.

EDIT 2:
When I import the React from 'react', now get a different error.
[image]

Comment: This error is suggests that there is an application already using the port 8080. This means that, if your app was running on the same port, then, you did not properly stop the server and as a result the app is still running there. You can fix this in one of two ways. One being, make sure you have stopped the server completely with CTRL+C or change the port your app is running in. I would suggest the first option.

Comment: Yeah, I just restarted it and everything seems fine now. Sorry for being such a noob and thank you! :D

Comment: Not a problem and no need to apologise :), we're all here to learn

Comment: Did you do ```import React from 'react';``` in the file you're rendering your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error suggests that there is an application already using the `Port` 8080. This means that, if your app was running in the same port, then, you did not properly stop the server and as a result the app is still running there. You can fix this in one of two ways:

1. Make sure you have stopped the server completely with CTRL+C
2. Change the port your app is running in.

I would suggest the first option.

Comment: Can I ask you for further assistance? I have updated the question. Thanx in advance.

Comment: It seems like you need to import React to your app like so: `import React from 'react'

Comment: Thanks. Further on with errors, I have updated the question again.